# How do i determine if my web host supports dot-net 4.5.1?

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, .net-4.5

Is there a simple script i can put on an Index.aspx page and upload to my web-host to determine if the target server supports .net 4.5.1?

The only method i can think of is not pretty:

Place distinctly 4.5.1 method calls in the code behind and expect an exception if the method is not supported.

There must better better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place following in your page:

```
<%=Environment.Version%>
```

This will give you something like:

```
4.0.30319.18444
```

Later you can determine that this corresponds to .Net framework 4.5.1 February 2014 Update using the article on wiki for [List of .NET Framework versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions).

You may also see: [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. the MSDN link points to some registry code... will give that a try from the index.aspx page